# A consequence of Schanuel's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, projective-module

In Carlson's *Cohomology and representation theory*, the author states Schanuel's lemma, and then derives a consequence that I cannot understand.

They define, for a $kG$ module $M$, $\Omega (M)$ to be the kernel of a surjective map $P\to M$ where $P$ is projective of minimal dimension (here I'm assuming dimension means "dimension over $k$" ); and then state that if $\gamma : Q\to M$ is another surjective map from a projective, then $\ker \gamma = \Omega( M) \oplus (\mathrm{proj})$, and say that it follows from Schanuel's lemma.

But I don't see how that follows from Schanuel's lemma. The exact statement is that $\ker \gamma \oplus P \cong \Omega(M)\oplus Q$, but I don't see why the isomorphism should take $\ker\gamma$ to $\Omega(M)\oplus$some projective submodule of $Q$ (actually the isomorphism I found when I wrote down a proof of the lemma doesn't send $\Omega(M)$ into $\ker \gamma$ at all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ingredient you're missing is the [Krull-Schmidt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem), which says that if you decompose a finite length module over a ring as a direct sum of indecomposable modules, the summands are unique up to isomorphism (and reordering).  In particular, let's decompose each term of $$\ker \gamma \oplus P \cong \Omega(M)\oplus Q$$ into indecomposable summands.  Since $\Omega(M)$ has no projective summands and $Q$ has only projective summands, we see that all the non-projective indecomposable summands of $\ker \gamma$ and $P$ must correspond to summands of $\Omega(M)$ and all the projective indecomposable summands of $\ker \gamma$ and $P$ must correspond to summands of $Q$.  But since $P$ is projective, all the non-projective summands must come from $\ker\gamma$.  This means that the decomposition of $\ker\gamma$ consists of all the summands of $\Omega(M)$ plus possibly some of the summands of $Q$.  That is, $\ker\gamma\cong \Omega(M)\oplus Q'$ for some projective module $Q'$.

Comment: And is there a way to deal with it if the modules don't have finite length ? (If they are infinite dimensional over $k$ )

Comment: Well, Carlson is only ever talking about finite-dimensional modules.  I believe the theory can be made to work for arbitrary modules, but you definitely need to change some things about the setup.  For instance, defining $\Omega(M)$ via a $P$ of minimal dimension is no good, since "minimal dimension" is a very weak condition when things are infinite-dimensional.

Comment: I believe the correct definition is to take a surjection $f:P\to M$ where $P$ is projective and $f$ does not restrict to a surjection on any proper submodule of $P$.  Using that definition, you can easily deduce that $\Omega(M)$ is a summand of $\ker\gamma$ for any other $\gamma:Q\to M$ by lifting $\gamma$ to a map $Q\to P$ which must be surjective by our condition on $f$.  Since $P$ is projective this map $Q\to P$ splits, and this gives a splitting of the entire short exact sequence $0\to\ker\gamma\to Q\to M\to 0$ with $0\to\Omega(M)\to P\to M\to 0$ as a summand.

Comment: Of course, with this definition you must do some work to prove that such an $f$ exists at all.

Comment: For what it's worth, when you work in the stable module category (which usually you can), none of these issues matter: you can just define $\Omega(M)$ as the kernel of _any_ surjection from a projective module to $M$, since they are all canonically isomorphic in the stable module category.  It's usually not actually very important that there is a "smallest" such module, and you can in fact set up the entire theory of these shifts $\Omega^n(M)$ as objects of the stable module category without any reference to the result you're asking about.

Comment: Oh right, like a projective cover of $M$ ? and yeah, I read that in the stable category all these worries went away, and I can see why, but I haven't worked with the stable category yet so I don't know what good it brings to work there (but that's for me to find out later) (Thank you for these comments !)